# Advanced review stats gives me an error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

When I try and click through to [Advanced review stats](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/admin/review/breakdown), I get the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error:

[image: oops]

I am not sure if this problem is exclusive to [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), but I could not find any previous reports here about it. There is no error if I try and access the Advanced review stats on Meta.GD

Comment: Works for me on scifi and outdoors.

Comment: Not working for me too on [reverseengineering.se]

Comment: This is working for me now, cc @AsheeshR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops!

Bug in some of the Internationalization work being done, will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: No juicy details from the dev assigned to the task? ;)